# Amplifying AC Current for Stepper Motor

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, current, motor, ac

I'm having troubles with a 3D printer. I need to change a motor for a more powerful one. For doing so, I 'll have to add an external small circuit to amplify the current but not the voltage given by the main board. After trying to understand the uses of MOSFET or OP amps, I feel a bit lost.

There's my configuration:

I can use an external 12v from the power supply
I need to get 1.7A from 0.9A (4V)

How do I amplify current for a stepper motor?

Comment: The simplest way to achieve that is using a 20 watt power audio op amp made for car stereos.

Comment: Configuration? Where?

Comment: It is not clear that you need a more powerful motor since you have no specs for torque, Supply, driver resistance , software,  config, and accelerate rate.  **Until then, you need to specify all of this.**  If you can't that proves my point, you need to learn basic stepper physics

Comment: Why can't you increase the voltage?  What kind of controller are you using?  Can you describe your setup in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

I think the practical answer to your question is that you can't put anything between the controller and the stepper motor.

Most 3d printers, and probably yours too use a dedicated stepper driver for each motor. These can microstep and regulate current. It's not a simple on/off sort of signal. If you put some device between the controller and motor then it's probably not going to work correctly.

You may be able to get a new motor that has windings such that that it generates more torque at same current as your old motor. You may also be able to increase the current setting of the driver by adjusting a pot on the board (if you're lucky), or by changing some surface mount resistors.

If none of that works, then I would try to find the step and direction signals, and simply replace the motor AND driver with something more powerful.

Comment: Yes changing the board for a RAMPS and get customize driver would be a solution, but I wanted indeed to get a cheaper solution.... If there is none... nevermind :P

Answer (score 1):

You can't amplify current for a stepper motor, the current is determined by the voltage and the load. To amplify the current for a stepper motor, you will need to change the motor coils and design itself.

The only real way to give a stepper motor more torque is to give it more voltage or to change the motor out for a bigger one. If you do increase the voltage, this can be done by changing the controller alone, but you can't exceed the voltage of the motor, so look at the datasheet and see what it's rated for.

Comment: Adding a bigger motor it's what I m trying to do... So if I put a bigger motor I ll still need a voltage amplifier as I can understand from you r answer?

Comment: An easier way would just to get a new controller, since adding a voltage amplifier will be difficult with the switching that needs to occur.